# What exactly do Iron Lockboxes contain?

Tags: spiral-knights

I received an [Iron Lockbox](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Usable#Lockboxes) today through the prize wheel.  I've checked the wiki, however, and it makes no mention of what items can be found inside the Iron Lockboxes.

What exactly can one find in an Iron Lockbox (list please)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added in the October 5, 2011 patch:

> Iron Lockboxes are the only way to find accessories. Any player can
>   find an Iron Lockbox and trade it with other players or put it up for
>   sale on the Auction House. Additionally, any item found within an Iron
>   Lockbox is also unbound and can be traded as well.

Only accessories can be found in lockboxes. Each lockbox has 0.1% chance of containing an aura, which comes in varying features.

Each accessory (with the exception of certain Wings) can come with any color, including the ever so rare Prismatic.

*List of colors:*

> - Cool
> - Divine
> - Dusky
> - Fancy
> - Heavy
> - Military
> - Regal
> - Sniped
> - Toasty
> - Volcanic
> - Prismatic

*List of accessories:*

> - Maid Headband
> - Mecha Wings
> - Auras
> - Barrell Belly
> - Com Unit
> - Plume
> - Wolver Tail

(will be updated)

Comment: Iron lockboxes are not the only way to get accesories. You can get them from event lockboxes and drops from monsters. Usual rare monsters such as impostocube which can drop prismatic toupe and dapper combo

Answer (score 2):

Gives random accesories, shadow keys (lots of them) , Cool Wolver Tail, and other stuffs which in that case are rare.

Comment: Can I get a link? Is there a list of items?

Comment: So can I get wings?  Is there certain items I cannot receive?  I'd like a more concise answer.